# Insert data in oracle database in python

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

I can't insert data into database using a dynamic query in python script

```
def execute_query(self, qo):
    query_string = "INSERT INTO " +dep_table+ " (client, sis, entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep,process, flag_dep_det) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % ("'CO'","'"+qo.db_src+"'","'"+qo.table_src+"'","'"+qo.table_des+"'","'"+qo.check_func+"'","'"+qo.table_des+"'","'NULL'")+";"
    cursor.execute(query_string)
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to set dependencies informations : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The connection to the database is okay, but I can't insert.

Comment: You shouldn't use the  `%` operator to insert values into your SQL. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: `%s` as a placeholder in SQL is _not the same_ as the string-formatting parameter in Python

Comment: `query_string = "INSERT INTO " + dep_table + " (client, sis, entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep,process, flag_dep_det) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", ("CO", qo.db_src, qo.table_src, qo.table_des, qo.check_func, qo.table_des, None)`. You can't parameterize table names, so you'll need to vet that against the schema of the db separately.

Comment: I tried using % but the same problem

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I got ERROR: Failed to set dependencies informations : expecting string, unicode or buffer object

Comment: Because I gave you a tuple. Get rid of `query_string = ...` and just use `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + dep_table + " (client, sis, entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep,process, flag_dep_det) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", ("CO", qo.db_src, qo.table_src, qo.table_des, qo.check_func, qo.table_des, None))`

Comment: I did, same ERROR: Failed to set dependencies informations : expecting string, unicode or buffer object

Comment: Then I have no idea. You haven't given enough information for us to debug this beyond "Here is an approach that is totally open to SQL-injection" along with a disembodied error. If the error points to a particular part of the query, you haven't shown it.

Comment: I give the query where I have the problem, any way thank you

Comment: The SQL libraries I have used give you an indication _where_ in the query there is an issue, not just "this query, somewhere, is wrong"

Answer (score 1):

Drop the semi-colon at the end of the string you are creating / executing.

It shouldn't be part of the SQL statement, rather used in some client tools to indicate the end of a statement so that the client can send it to the database to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem
`connection.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` method in Python like below:

```
def execute_query(self, qo):
    query_string = "INSERT INTO {0} (client, sis, entity_name_1, entity_name_2, flag_dep,process, flag_dep_det) VALUES ('{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', {7})".format(dep_table, 'CO', qo.db_src, qo.table_src, qo.table_des, qo.check_func, qo.table_des, 'NULL')
    cursor.execute(query_string)
```